# Distributing Java Application that uses JRI and R

Tags: java, r, packaging, jri

So I am working on a Java Application that uses the JRI library to talk to R (developed in Eclipse on Windows 7). In order to get JRI to work, I had to modify a bunch of environment variables (PATH, R_HOME, R_LIBS_USER) in order to have JRI be able to talk to R and use all of the installed user libraries. Since these are all specific to my system, how do I make it so when I make it distributable it is able to detect the location of the users R installation? Do I have to make the user set all of these environment variables as part of setup? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [JGR](http://rforge.net/JGR) launchers - they do exactly that (on Windows and Mac OS X). They detect R location and set variables accordingly before launching Java. The sources are in the `launcher` directory of the sources (see https://svn.rforge.net/JGR/trunk/launcher/).

PS: please use [stats-rosuda-devel](http://mailman.rz.uni-augsburg.de/mailman/listinfo/stats-rosuda-devel) mailing list for questions on rJava/JRI/JGR ..